# How to create a list of open image command from an image list

Tags: python, list, image

I need to create a list of open image commands from an image list. I have to do it like that, instead of doing the "open image" inside a for because I need to pass to a function the data in this exact format.

Let me explain better.

This is the format that I have:

`img_my_list=['img_1.png','img_2.png', 'img_3.png']`

This is the format that i need for my function (I cannot use a for inside my function):

```
img_open_format_list = [(open(join(dirname(__file__), 'img_1.png'), 'rb'), 'image/png'),
        (open(join(dirname(__file__), 'img_2.png'), 'rb'), 'image/png'),
        (open(join(dirname(__file__), 'img_3.png'), 'rb'), 'image/png')]
```

How can I transform the list?

Comment: When is it jpeg and when is it png? And why can't you use a `for` loop?

Comment: Open should be used as context manager OR it closing is your responsibility, this seems to be a bad design by the first glance.

Comment: png vs jpeg was an error in the question. 
And I cannot use `for` because in Relatorio library (the one that I am using) you can only pass data parameters, and the way to pass the pictures is with the open statement. The library: https://relatorio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickexample.html#data

Answer (score 1):

Every `open` should be accompanied by a `close` unless used as a context manager.

The [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) is perfectly suited for that task.

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack

img_my_list=['img_1.png','img_2.png', 'img_3.png']

with ExitStack() as stack:
    images = [(stack.enter_context(open(img, 'rb')), 'image/png') for img in img_my_list]
    ...  # do work
```

As you exit the scope, all opened images will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out that it can be done with `map`:

`img_my_list = ['img_1.png','img_2.png', 'img_3.png']`

```
img_open_command_list = map(lambda x: (open(x, 'rb'), 'image/png'), img_my_list)
```

This way I get the open command list that I desire by doing: `list(img_open_command_list)`. And the images are attached perfectly in my report.

Comment: If you need `list(map(...))` then you can (or should) use a list comprehension `[... for x in y]`.